# I added "background-image" via CSS in Wordpress twenty-seventeen: doesn't display

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image

I want to override Wordpress's Twenty-Seventeen header image by adding my own background-image via CSS. However, it just displays blank white... Here's the body's html:

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-5 logged-in wp-custom-logo has-header-image page-one-column title-tagline-hidden colors-light page-soins" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="400" data-aos-delay="0" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
```

and here's my CSS to disable wordpress's header image:

```
.page-soins .wp-custom-header {
     display: none;
}
```

and here's my CSS to add my background image instead:

```
body.page-soins {
    background: url("images/backgrounds/soins-bg-1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Finally, here's the link to the page: `http://latelierdegaia.ch/soins`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Instead of adding it to .page-soins, add it to .site-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.site-content-contain
```

and

```
.site-mast-head
```

both have

```
background-color: #fff;
```

which covers your `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that works around! But does the trick. I just added the CSS background-image to the "site-header" class instead of the "body".

```
body.page-soins .site-header {
    background: url("images/backgrounds/soins-bg-1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove `background-color: #fafafa;` from your `.site-header` class.